# Run gradle task X after "connectedAndroidTest" task is successful

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle `taskX` that I would like to run after `connectedAndroidTest` task finishes, however only if all tests pass in `connectedAndroidTest`.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to utilize [`finalizedBy`](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34797260) along with particular task's state checking. Here's how it can be done:

```
task connectedAndroidTest << {
  logger.lifecycle("Running $name")
  if (project.hasProperty('lol')) {
    throw new Exception('lol')
  }
}

task taskX << {
  def failure = tasks.connectedAndroidTest.state.failure
  if(!failure) {
    logger.lifecycle("$name is finalizer")
  } else {
    logger.lifecycle("$tasks.connectedAndroidTest.name failed, nothing to do.")
  }
}

connectedAndroidTest.finalizedBy(taskX)
```

Now if run with:

```
gradle cAT
```

the output will be:

```
:connectedAndroidTest
Running connectedAndroidTest
:taskX
taskX is finalizer

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.889 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

When:

```
gradle cAT -Plol
```

is run, then the output is:

```
:connectedAndroidTest
Running connectedAndroidTest
:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
:taskX
connectedAndroidTest failed, nothing to do.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/opal/tutorial/stackoverflow/34797260/build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectedAndroidTest'.
> lol

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.931 secs
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34797260) a demo can be found.

```
  [1]: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy(java.lang.Object...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're describing Task Dependencies. You can define a task that depends on another, and will therefore trigger the other when it is executed:

```
task taskX(dependsOn: 'connectedAndroidTest') << {
   //do something
}
```

And then just run your task, and `connectedAndroidTest` will be execute first:

```
gradle taskX
```

[Task Dependency docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies)

Comment: `finalizedBy` is not enough in this case.