# Android Test Sharding with Spoon

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, spoon

I am using Spoon and Espresso to automate UI/Functional instrumentation tests on our android app.

I would like to know if there is a way to distribute instrumentation tests across the multiple connected devices and/or emulators so that i can reduce the test execution time.

Ex: I have say 300 tests that take 15 mins to run on 1 emulator. Is there a way i can add more emulators (say 4), distribute 75 tests to each emulator and reduce the test execution time?

Appreciate your inputs on this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [auto-sharding](https://github.com/square/spoon#test-sharding). You have to call the spoon-runner with `--shard` and add the serials from all connected devices with `-serial`. You can find the serials with `adb devices`.

Comment: Thanks. This is the option i tried. But am seeing espresso tests failing randomly when i add two or more emulators and do auto-sharding. However, if i have only one emulator, there are no random test failures. Have you come across this issue?

Comment: regarding your randomly failing tests, I have experienced similar failures with real devices in particular. But it turns out that it's the actual implementation issues, eg. multi threading since instrumentation is running in a different thread. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd like to add my two cents here, even we faced the same problem that is some random tests started failing after we used shard option. We found out tests that were failing were dependent on other tests which are now running on a different device, so we had to fix those tests and made them completely independent and it worked as expected. 
but sometimes it could be because of the reason @WenChao mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose more than one device in Choose dialog. Press `Shift` or `CTRL` key when click.

Another solution is to use `Gradle`. On the right side of Android Studio choose `Gradle`, then `verification`, finally `connectedAndroidTest`. It would give you the same effect as you would put in console:

`./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` or `gradlew.bat connectedAndroidTest`

I mean I would run all test cases on all available devices (physical and emulators). For choosing exactly which test classes you should make **tasks** in `build.gradle`.

Learn basics of `Groovy` programming language to make writing Gradle task scripts more effectively. Here's an example of task written in Groovy: [Run gradle task X after "connectedAndroidTest" task is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797260/run-gradle-task-x-after-connectedandroidtest-task-is-successful)

You may also learn about `Continuous Integration` and its tools like `Jenkins`, or `Travis`, which you can configure to run specific test cases on every commit.
As an example please take a look at this build log of my Android project: https://travis-ci.org/piotrek1543/WeatherforPoznan/builds/126944044 
and here is a configuration of Travis: https://github.com/piotrek1543/WeatherforPoznan/blob/master/.travis.yml

Have any more question? Please free to ask.

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am sorry if I was not clear with my query in this post.  As part of continuous integration, we run around 500 tests on an Android emulator for every commit pushed by developer. This is currently taking 25 mins and it would increase as we add more tests. I was looking here for a way to reduce the execution time by distributing these 500 tests to two or more Android emulators of exactly same configuration. Please suggest if you have any thoughts around this.

Comment: Hey @PavanAgarwal Did you solve your problem ? if yes can you tell me how ? i am trying spoon but it is not picking up all the test in my testpackage. Also, i can see it is running test on emulator one by one. i.e. one emulator at a time. Please help ?? thanks in advance.